# Fetch Data of two tables and insert to new table

Tags: android, sqlite, multiple-tables

I have three activities in my application with following names:
**Activity #1**
**Activity #2**
**Activity Final**

Also for each activity, I have a table with following names:
**Table #1**
**Table #2**
**Table Final**

Default value of **Qty** column is **"0"** and users will change it at run-time.

I've created **Table#1** and **Table#2** and they work fine.

I just don't know how can I add rows of **Table#1** and **Table#2** where **"Qty"** is bigger than **"0"** into **Table Final**.

[image: table structure]

**Note:** id column of each tables is PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: What is the error you are getting after implementing @CL's answer?

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia, when I call **insertFinalTable()** the application would be crashed !!!

Comment: Do not change the question to something else; this would invalidate the answers. If you have another problem, ask a new question. (Also see [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).)

Comment: @CL., Tanks for your hint ;)
I've edited my question because of :
1. my problem didn't solve and I added more explains ...
2. I didn't see **Answer Your Question** button to add more explains ...

Comment: @CL., What should I do?!
Add extra explains by **add answer to my question** or **ask new question** ?!

Comment: An answer is not a question. To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO "Table Final"(Product, Qty)
SELECT Product, Qty FROM "Table #1" WHERE Qty > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT Product, Qty FROM "Table #2" WHERE Qty > 0;
```

Comment: Dear CL, Tanks a lot for your answer.
I've not known **UNION ALL** at all !!!
[Unfortunately, I can't Vote your answer because of I'm new member of **StackOverFlow** ]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union`wordkey to achieve this.

```
INSERT INTO Final(Product, Qty)
(SELECT Product, Qty FROM t1 where Qty > 0)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Product, Qty FROM t2 where Qty > 0)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not valid SQL.

Comment: Dear ZOZELFELFO, Tanks for your answer, too.
Just I have to edit it to SQL Command ...