# Update table that created based on other tables (by UNION ALL)

Tags: android, sqlite

I've created a final table that fetched data from two other tables by **UNION ALL** statement [with this Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947396/fetch-data-of-two-tables-and-insert-to-new-table) 
Now I have new problem with updating table final. 
When I want update **"final_qty"** , **"firts_qty"** or **"second_qty"** must be updated. 
But I don't know how can I do it !  
This is my codes:

**// Table Names**

```
public static final String TBL_FIRST = "table_first"; 
public static final String TBL_SECOND = "table_second"; 
public static final String TBL_FINAL = "table_final";
```

**//Table Fisrt Columns**

```
private static final String KEY_FIRST_ID = "first_id"; 
private static final String KEY_FIRST_PRODUCT = "first_product"; 
private static final String KEY_FIRST_QTY = "first_qty";
```

**//Table Second Columns**

```
private static final String KEY_SECOND_ID = "second_id"; 
private static final String KEY_SECOND_PRODUCT = "second_product"; 
private static final String KEY_SECOND_QTY = "second_qty";
```

**//Table Final Columns**

```
private static final String KEY_FINAL_ID = "final_id"; 
private static final String KEY_FINAL_PRODUCT = "final_product"; 
private static final String KEY_FINAL_QTY = "final_qty";
```

**// Create Statements**

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FIRST = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_FIRST + "(" + 
KEY_FIRST_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
KEY_FIRST_PRODUCT + " TEXT," + 
KEY_FIRST_QTY + " INTEGER" + ")"; 

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SECOND = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_SECOND + "(" + 
KEY_SECOND_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
KEY_SECOND_PRODUCT + " TEXT," + 
KEY_SECOND_QTY + " INTEGER" + ")"; 

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FINAL = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_FINAL + "(" + 
KEY_FINAL_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
KEY_FINAL_PRODUCT + " TEXT," + 
KEY_FINAL_QTY + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

**// INSERT DATA TO FINAL TABLE**

```
"INSERT INTO " + TBL_FINAL + "(" + 
KEY_FINAL_PRODUCT + "," + KEY_FINAL_QTY + ")" + 
" SELECT " + KEY_FIRST_PRODUCT + "," + KEY_FIRST_QTY +  
" FROM " + TBL_FIRST + " WHERE " + KEY_FIRST_QTY + ">" + 0 + 
"UNION ALL SELECT " + KEY_SECOND_PRODUCT + "," + KEY_SECOND_QTY + 
" FROM " + TBL_SECOND + " WHERE " + KEY_SECOND_QTY + ">" + 0  ;
```

This is sample of my activities.

[Sample image](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/09/27/Untitled-1.jpg)

In **main activity** I can go to **first** or **second** or **final** activities. When I'm in **first** or **second** activities, I change their **items quantities** and I return to the **main activity**. 
Then I click on **Final button** in actionBar and go to **Final Activity**. In this Activity I'm going to change **items quantities**, so in addition to **final_table**, **first_table** and **second_table** items quantities must be updated.

---

Also When I go to my first activity and update **"first_qty"**, in my **"Final Table"** I have two same rows with different qty.

**Any offers would be appreciated.**

Comment: Why do you have the final table in the first place?

Comment: @CL. Where u suggest define it ?!
Please mention to my below answer descriptions.

Comment: 1 - Can't you use the `final table` **directly**? 2 - Try to use `INSERT OR REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, I can use final_table, but when I'm going to update its items quntities, items quantities of other tables don't update!

Comment: And why do you need the other tables? OR why isn't the "final table" a **view**, instead? It would be always the mirror of the other two tables contents...

Comment: I'm new in sqlite (and other databases) !!!
Could you tell me how can I use a view instead final table ?!

Comment: See the official docs: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html. Or see this for more detailed info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, Tanks a lot for your documents. I'm reading them but as I understand, I can't update VIEW ...

Comment: NO. A View is just to be READ. You only update the **original Tables**. And then see the results reflected in the View.

Comment: If you check my image link, I need to update quantities in final activity.
But in VIEW I can't do it.
Also, how can I fetch deta of VIEW and show in ListView ?!

Comment: Is there any suggestion(s) ?!!!